# lxml find element by name, but use variable in search

Tags: python, lxml

I have a problem with the find function in lXML. But i think this is more a generic question how to tell that i want to check against the value, not the object reference.

So here is the code that works:

```
step = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()="Design"]').getparent()
```

If i try to replace the string with an object, the result is always None.

```
stepn = 'Design'
step = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()=stepn]').getparent()

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getparent'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stepn = 'Design'
step = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={}]'.format(stepn)).getparent()
```

when you use `' '`, it's a string , any element in string will be treated as a string, not a variable.

Use `format` to add variable to string

Comment: 'step = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={}]'.format(stepn)).getparent()'
ValueError: zero length field name in format So i edited it to 'step = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={0}]'.format(stepn)).getparent()
    print type(step)'  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getparent'