# lxml find element by text attribute in xml by using a variable in find expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I have a problem parsing a XML object with find.

I read my XML objects from a http response with were response is the html body I get from my http routine:

```
xml_obj = objectify.XML(response)
```

This is my XML Object:

```
print etree.tostring(xml_obj, pretty_print=True)

<kids>
  <kid>
    <id>110</id>
    <name>Peter</name> 
  </kid>
  <kid>
    <id>111</id>
    <name>Paul</name>
  </kid>
  <kid>
    <id>112</id>
    <name>Mary</name>
  </kid>
  <kid>
    <id>113</id> 
    <name>Jane</name>
  </kid>
</kids>
```

This is my code to search for a kid by name:

```
kid_obj = xml_obj.find(‘.//kid/name[text()=“Jane”]’).getparent()
print etree.tostring(kid_obj, pretty_print=True)

<kid>
  <id>113</id> 
  <name>Jane</name>
</kid>
```

As soon as i replace the string with a variable it does not work:

```
kidname = “Jane”
kid_obj = xml_obj.find(‘.//kid/name[text()=kidname]').getparent()
print etree.tostring(kid_obj, pretty_print=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getparent'
```

This does not work either:

```
kidname = “Jane”
kid_obj = xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={0}]’.format(kidname)).getparent()
print etree.tostring(kid_obj, pretty_print=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getparent'
```

After I slept over it for a night I finally found a working solution, but maybe not the most elegant code:

```
kidname = 'Jane'
kid_obj = xml_obj.find('.//kid/name[text()="'+kidname+'"]').getparent()
print etree.tostring(kid_obj, pretty_print=True)

<kid>
  <id>113</id> 
  <name>Jane</name>
</kid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41985178/407651

Answer (score 0):

In the first one

```
xml_obj.find(‘.//kid/name[text()=kidname]’)
```

"kidname" is seen as a value and not a variable. A quick test would be to rename one of the kids with the name "kidname".

In the second one

```
xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={0}]’.format(kidname))
```

You're not using the same the quotes, (' and then ’).

Could you try:

```
xml_obj.find('.//step/name[text()={0}]'.format(kidname))
```

Answer (score 0):

First example:

```
kidname = 'Jane'
kid_obj = xml_obj.find('.//kid/name[text()="{}"]'.format(kidname)).getparent()
print etree.tostring(kid_obj, pretty_print=True)
```

Second example:

```
kidname = 'Jane'
kids = xml_obj.find('.//kid')
success = False
for kid in kids:
    for property in kid: 
       if property.tag == 'name' and property.text == kidname:
           success = True
    if success:
       break
print etree.tostring(kid, pretty_print=True)
```

Note, that possible error when no kid with kidname found isn't handled in both examples.